# Access current product collection in 2-columns-left

Tags: magento-1.9, template, product-collection

I need to access the current product collection in teh main page template (in this case 2-columns-left) in order to check whether a certain product exists, and if it does, display a banner advert.

I have tried:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

but this loads all products, not just the ones loaded into the product list template.

Is there a way I can access only those products listed in the product view template from the parent template (2-columns-left)?

Comment: Are you trying to find the product collection in list.phtml?

Comment: No, in 2-columns-left - in terms of the layout the banner appears above the list.phtml in the page

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

> Mage::registry('current_category')->getProductCollection();

Regards, Diego.

Answer (score 0):

Mat, you can use the following code,

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($currentCategory){
   $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection($currentCategory);               
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks.